# Indy TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL - it works on my PC, not on my friend's

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

My application is using `TIdHTTP.Get` to access ClickBank's API. In order for that to work, I have to assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler`.

The problem is, that the above setup works fine on my PC (the dev box), however when I send it out to my friends, they get the Forbidden (403) error.

Could it be that they are missing the OpenSSL libaries? I did a search on my PC, and a bunch of apps that my buddys have, includes SLL libraries.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

My bad - The **Libeay32.dll** and **Ssleay32.dll** has to be in either the Windows directory, or in your App's directory.

Comment: Or better to say in one of the locations specified by [these rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).